# Is it possible to compile Java Bytecode to Native Code using pypy?

Tags: jvm, pypy

pypy currently translates Rpython to Native code using Pluggable JIT and GC. Currently it has a Python frontend . I am wondering if it is possible to  write a Java Bytecode frontend  to pypy making an alternate cool JVM (written in (R)Python)

Answer (score 3):

An RPython interpreter for Java bytecode wouldn't be a compiler for Java bytecode to native code. The RPython code is compiled to native code, not the code the interpreter is interpreting.

At runtime (some-of) the interpreted code would be JIT-compiled to native code, but that's completely different, and the HotSpot VM already does this. Given that HotSpot has been developed over a long period of time with serious resources behind it, and specifically tuned for Java, I doubt you could get anything even approaching as good as it out of PyPy.

PyPy's strength is the idea that you can write things like garbage collectors and JIT compilers as a framework that works **independently of the languages you're interpreting**. Then lots of people can write lots of interpreters for lots of languages, and write them in a fairly high-level easy-to-code way, but they still all get high quality GCs, JIT compilers, etc without having to specifically implement them for each language. PyPy is unlikely to be a reasonable alternative to an existing project that has already sunk huge amounts of resources into developing highly optimised GCs and JIT compilers that are specifically tuned for their language.

Comment: It's maybe also worth noting that pypy's JIT is specifically tuned towards **dynamic** languages. Chances are it'll not perform as well for static ones.